# Is it possible to lose data on sudden power loss for emulated EEPROM of PIC?

Tags: pic

I want to use emulated EEPROM feature on PIC24FJ128GB106 chip since it do not have internal EEPROM.

However, although it is not clearly mentioned on its datasheet (AN1095 document), I think data is temporarily stored on holding latch before pack operation. If then, I think data could be lost on sudden power loss before pack operation.

Is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible!

You must ensure that controller have enough electrical power to finish FLASH block write. Single FLASH block write takes about 3 ms. So you must use low voltage detect circuit which interrupt the main program and put the controller in low power consumption to finish FLASH write 100% (use big enough capacitor on Vdd).